# Область видимости при запуске из функции Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, websocket

Здравствуйте уважаемые участники ресурса.
У меня есть скрипт который запускает Websocket. Получается я могу открыть соединение передать данные на сервер но не могу отрисовать. Вот код.

```
var ws = ""

$("#author").on('click', function(e){
    if(ws){
      ws.close()
    }
    else{
      ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/')

});

$('#send').on('click', function(e){
   let message = $('#input-message').value
   ws.send(
      JSON.stringify({
         'message': message,
      })
});

ws.onmessage = function(e){
      const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
      message.innerHTML += '<li class="msg">' + data.message +'</li>'
}
```

ws.onmessage не работает. Подскажите как истравить. Не очень силён в javascript

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что `ws.onmessage` не работает?

Comment: В ней даже console.log() не отображается.  Значит она не отрабатывает.

Comment: а ты что-то шлешь _из_ вебсокета? В вопросе код только для одного направления

Comment: В ответе из сокета тоже сообщение. Если вынести подключение из события то всё работает. Но мне нужно устанавливать соединение при определённых действиях.

Comment: а, ну так обработчик надо добавлять, когда у тебя в переменной websocket лежит а не строка ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объект `WebSocket` создается только внутри обработчика события.

До вызова обработчика в переменной хранится пустая строка. Поэтому фактически

```
ws.onmessage = function(e){
```

добавляется строке и полностью переписывается при присваивании нового значения

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/')
```

Для решения достаточно перенести добавление обработчика в место, где создается WebSocket

```
var ws = ""

$("#author").on('click', function(e){
    if(ws){
      ws.close()
    }
    else{
      ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/')
      ws.onmessage = function(e){
          const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
          message.innerHTML += '<li class="msg">' + data.message +'</li>'
      }    
    }
});

$('#send').on('click', function(e){
   let message = $('#input-message').value
   ws.send(
      JSON.stringify({
         'message': message,
      })
});
```